# How to integrate Google Analytics into GWT using the asynchronous script

Tags: java, gwt, google-analytics

I'm trying to track pages using Google Analytics within a GWT application.
I already check the following thread: [Integrating Google Analytics into GWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457794/integrating-google-analytics-into-gwt-application)

I think that the solution:

```
public static native void recordAnalyticsHit(String pageName) /*-{
$wnd.pageTracker._trackPageview(pageName);}-*/;
```

only works using the synchronous GA script.

I'm trying with the following:

```
public native void trackHit (String pageName) /*-{
  try {
    $wnd._gaq.push (['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX']);
    $wnd._gaq.push (['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']);
    $wnd._gaq.push (['_trackPageview', pageName]);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('failure on gaq' + err);
  }
}-*/;
```

And is not working for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are my page- and event-tracking functions:

```
public static native void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) /*-{
    $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label]);
}-*/;

public static native void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label, int intArg) /*-{
    $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, intArg]);
}-*/;

public static native void trackPageview(String url) /*-{
    $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
}-*/;
```

I do the _setAccount stuff like normal in the host page (needs to execute before trackPageview() etc will work:

```
<!-- Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-FAKE1234-2']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

You don't need to use setAccount every time you post an event, only at the beginning.  I don't bother with try{}catch{} stuff... I don't actually know JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new version of Google Analytics out which uses a new analytics.js script.  It's the same process though, just add the script in your html header:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-YOUR_ACCOUNT-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And then can call the new methods like so:

```
public static native void googleAnalyticsTrackPageView(String url) /*-{
    $wnd.ga('send', 'pageview', url);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a project on goole code called gwt-gatracker that implement GA function to use in GWT projects. [check it out here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-gatracker/)