# How do I integrate Google Analytics into GWT applications?

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, google-analytics

I have two problems...1. I have never used google analytics, and 2.  I have never used, made, or touched a GWT project until now.  I am trying to get google analytics to work with a GWT application.  I read through this: [How to integrate Google Analytics into GWT using the asynchronous script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785036/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-into-gwt-using-the-asynchronous-script) and the question that it links to with no luck.

> There is a new version of Google Analytics out which uses a new
>   analytics.js script. It's the same process though, just add the script
>   in your html header:
>
> ```
> <script>
> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
> (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
> m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
> })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
>
> ga('create', 'UA-YOUR_ACCOUNT-X', 'auto');
> ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>
> ```

For my case, the project is large and I am not sure which html file I need to put the google analyics js in.  I am assuming the html files in the war folder.

**As for this bit:**

> call the new methods like so:
>
> ```
> public static native void googleAnalyticsTrackPageView(String url)/*-{
> $wnd.ga('send', 'pageview', url); }-*/;
> ```

I am totally unsure where I need to include this.

Oh, one last question.  Is this still how I would test locally?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'none'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your war folder there should be an index.html or index.jsp file that serves the GWT JS file (xxx-nocache.js). You need to put the script there.

Alternatively you can also use Arcbee's [universal-analytics](https://github.com/ArcBees/universal-analytics) library.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much.  What about the calling the methods portion?

I will look into Arcbee's library.

Comment: You can define the `public static native void googleAnalyticsTrackPageView` in your `EntryPoint` or in a utility class and then call that function from any Java class in your GWT app. Under the hood it will just call the google analytics javascript function for pageview.